# Modify URL and add parameter in between the URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, url, addition

I have a long list of urls to be modified.

For example the url is:

```html
https://somedomain.com/?pid=24787CL22311&source=linkkit&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.demo.com
```

So in the above url I want to add subid=1233 just before the &source=linkkit

like this:

```html
 https://some.com/?pid=24787CL22311&subid=1233&source=linkkit&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.demo.com
```

I tried with append, set and replace but did not gave the specific result

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why do you need to add it before? It's a query string so no matter where you add it..

Comment: The order of parameters in the url doesn't matter unless your endpoint is parsing it explicitly and requires that order

Comment: Well, when the actual url is opened in the browser it tracks some data and redirects the url to www.demo.com @PatrickEvans

Comment: @KamleshKatpara that has nothing to do with the order of parameters, unless you are saying that doesnt happen when you just simply append the parameter

Comment: The order doesn't matter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

let url = 'https://some.com/?pid=24787CL22311&subid=1233&source=linkkit&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.demo.com';

url = url.replace('&source=', '&subid=1233&source=')

Comment: It worked, thanks guys.
And yes you both are right.
I believe I missed something